# How to execute Wix custom action after installation?

Tags: wix, action

I am using Wix3 to install WCF service to IIS.

How can I use my custom action (c#) function after installation completed? i.e. I need to open installed web.config file and replace hostname with real one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

You can schedule it after [InstallFinalize](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_installfinalize.htm) action in [InstallExecuteSequence](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_installexecutesequence.htm).

Comment: Accurate for sequencing it when he wants, but Christoper's answer is a better solution for what he actually wants to accomplish.

Answer (score 9):

There is a sequence of Actions in Windows Installer. The WiX tutorial has a [good section](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/extra-actions/) on events (and is a great resource anyway).

A typical example of getting something to run after InstallFinalize is to get the installed app to start.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action='LaunchFile' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: If your `CustomAction` is using the `ExeCommand` property of the `CustomAction` to execute a script command, this won't work and reports a compile time error of: "*[Insert Action ID Name] is a in-script custom action. It must be sequenced in between the InstallInitialize action and the InstallFinalize action in the InstallExecuteSequence table*"

Answer (score 6):

Why would you:

1) Need a custom action?
2) Do it after the install instead of during the install?

WiX has a built-in extension for handling what you are trying to do:

[XmlFile Element (Util Extension)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm)

It will update your XML after the file has been installed and handle rollback scenarios as well.

What you will have to write a CA for though is reading the XML value back into a property ti handle repair and upgrade situations.  Read:

[The WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern).

Comment: help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264361/failed-to-open-xml-file-wix-unable-to-update-appsettings-json