# Create a file with installation status in WiX

Tags: c#, wix

I have a WiX installer that I want to use to create a file post-install that is filled with XML with some data about the install process. I am not sure how to go about doing it and am wondering if anyone can help or point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute Wix custom action after installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044069/how-to-execute-wix-custom-action-after-installation)

Comment: Saw that, however, still unsure of where to start. Do I need to create an executable and run that post install? How do I specify what to run? How can I pass if it was a success or failure. If it was a failure, how do I grab the exception that was thrown (if it was an exception). That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at custom actions and properties [at firegiant.com](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/extra-actions/) and [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27101890/5168962).

```
<Property Id='status'>Error | Success</Property>
<CustomAction Id='AfterInstall' Property='status' ExeCommand='[SourceDir]Readme.txt' Return='asyncNoWait' />
```

That's what I found. I have no experience so I just rely on the sources given. Hope it helps