# Failed to open XML file - Wix unable to update appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3

I am using `Wix` to create `MSI` installers. My requirement is to pass `parameters` while installing `msi` from the command line and `update' the`appsettings.json` with the values passed.

To achieve this, I have added below property and component.

```
  <Property Id="ApplicationLog.pathFormat" />


  <Component Id="config" Guid="*">
    <File Id="appconfig" Source="$(var.BasePath)\appsettings.json" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes"/>
    <util:XmlFile 
      Id="_pathFormat_" File="$(var.BasePath)\appsettings.json"  
      Action="setValue" 
      Name="pathFormat" Value="[pathFormat]" 
      ElementPath="/ApplicationLog/Serilog/WriteTo/Args/"
      Sequence='1' />
  </Component>
```

I have passed the values as follow while installing

> C:\work\Installer\bin\Debug>MyService-Debug-x86.msi pathFormat="value1"

But I get below error

> Failed to open XML file  ....\Installer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\win-x86\publish\appsettings.json. system error -2147024786

**Additional Information**

There was ICE30 error,

> ICE30: The target file 'l-racj8d.jso|appsettings.json' is installed in '[ProgramFilesFolder]\MyService\' by two different components on an LFN system: 'config' and 'cmpF82FCA80BBAF44D285C97F10993DEEE6'.

Which resolved by changing the `ICE validation`-> `Suppress ICE validation`

But why installer unable to open the `json` app settings?  I am running the installer in administrator mode.

**Update**

I have changed `$(var.BasePath)` to '[INSTALLDIR]'

```
  <Component Id='config' Guid='*'>
    <File Id='jsonconfig' Source='[INSTALLDIR]appsettings.json' KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes"/>
    <util:XmlFile Id='xpathFormat' File='[INSTALLDIR]appsettings.json'
                  Action='setValue' Name='pathFormat' Value='[ApplicationLog.pathFormat]'
                  ElementPath='/ApplicationLog/Serilog/WriteTo/Args/' Sequence='1' />
  </Component>
```

But I am getting

> The system cannot find the file '[INSTALLDIR]appsettings.json'.

Is it because `appsettings.json` is not yet copied to [INSTALLDIR]?? If yes, then how to achieve this?

Comment: Using `XmlFile` to update JSON file? How does that work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wix, but I would add: 1) Properties passed on the command line should be upper case (i.e, a public property - PATHFORMAT).  2)  Why would you want to suppress ICE validation?  3)  Make sure you schedule the XmlFile part to run after the InstallFiles standard action. 4)  What @Dialecticus said!

Comment: How to schedule XmlFile to run after standard actions? Is there post-install actions supported by Wix?

Comment: @Dialecticus  I am not sure, there is no JsonFile component in wix

Comment: There is no such thing. It does not exist. You have two options, either make your own custom action, or update the configuration from your app (instead of from msi). So, your app would somehow detect that config should be changed, and must have the parameters to update, and maybe even have to do this in a new process with admin privileges.

Comment: Maybe there is something of use on github, or nuget, or elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, I found one solution approach here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805767/wix-custom-actions-reading-parameters-from-an-xml-file  but not sure from where he got "Session" as parameter

Comment: Every custom action has only that one parameter. A custom action must then read actual parameters from some table within msi using that one parameter.